# 160°C fan forced or 325°F convection

Tags: convection

I have  recipe that recommends 160°C fan forced for approximately 1 hour.

I have a convection feature on my stove, so should I use it at 325°F with the convection on or just 325°F direct heat?  It is a gas oven.

Comment: The recipe asks for convection and it sounds like you have that feature available. Is there a reason you think it isn't appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

If your oven allows, 320°F is closer to 160°C, but I know some ovens are bit clunky and only go 25 degrees at a step.

Since "Fan Forced" is just another term for "Convection" you should use the fan if the recipe recommends it.